# malformed links send by swiftmail

Tags: html, symfony, email, twig

Good morning,

I just finished the implementation of [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) combined with Twig templates. I have sent several mails now and I encountered a strange habit.

For example:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/">Example</a>
```

Sends me a link in the following format:

```
x-webdoc://AAAAAAAA-BBBB-2222-CC33-DDDDDD444444/example.com/
```

to my apple mail account. But when i change the value between the < a >-Tags to this

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/">Example.com</a>
```

I can open the link without any Problem. I can't understand that behaviour.
Can anyone explain this to me? Couldn't test sending mails to gmail or any other provider, since my dev environment can't yet sent mails out of it.

I hope you can help me.

Regards

Comment: It's Apple™ Inc. that breaks it. Just google for "apple x-webdoc" --- there are a lot of complains about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll check some more links later that day.